# Debye Function Integral (BlackBody)

Tags: integration, power-series, mathematical-physics

Show that

$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x^{3} \, dx}{e^{x}-1} = \frac{\pi^{4}}{15} $$

by expanding the integrand in powers of $e^{-x} $ and integrating term by term.

Could anyone help with this one?

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^{x}-1}~dx ~=~ n!~\zeta(n+1),~$ and $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^{x}+1}~dx ~=~ n!~\eta(n+1).~$ See the [Riemann $\zeta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) functions for more information.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-(n+1)x}$$

Can you finish the rest?